# An antonym for "shortcut"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I know it isn't "[longcut](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=longcut)", although the term is used sometimes, humorously.

How do I correct someone who believes a way to be the shortest route when it is in fact

- a longer route, or
- the longest route.

> It's not a shortcut, it's a ______ (preferably single word)

Please note that I'm not looking for a way to paraphrase this. It's just an example sentence. I'm looking for a word that specifically serves as an antonym to shortcut, in this sense and [others](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shortcut).

---

**EDIT:** Dan's comment below: *"I'm struggling to find reasons why one would want longer-than-normal routes. The 'antonym' doesn't seem to make sense"*, calls for an edit.

Let's say there are two paths: One shortcut and the other, for the lack of a better term, longcut.

You might wish to take the longcut if:

1. Someone you like is in the passenger seat and you want it to last as long as possible.
2. As Mary pointed out, the shortcut might require you to drive on a hellish road.
3. You're a cab driver and want to extract the maximum fare. (It's based on distance travelled here in India.)
4. The shortcut is shorter in distance but might take longer to navigate: traffic jams, accidents... any number of reasons.
5. You feel like it.

Comment: "detour"? "Scenic Route"?  In your example sentence, I'd probably say "it's not a shortcut, it's actually longer" or "a longer way around" or something like that.

Comment: @Hellion: I know. That's what I say. Hence the search for an antonym.

Comment: Yeah, "scenic route" is idiomatic.

Comment: @Hellion I think you have nailed it. Why don't you make it an answer :)?

Comment: @SamuelVimes, JonPurdy already said basically the same thing, I've got nothing to add to his answer.  :-)

Comment: There's a good reason for the word 'shortcut': people often want to get somewhere more quickly.  A short cut is, usually, a good thing.  I'm struggling to find reasons why one would want longer-than-normal routes.  The 'antonym' doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @Dan "Taking shortcuts" can also mean "cutting corners."

Comment: @Dan: Ever driven the girl of your dreams home?

Comment: @Dan sometimes "shortcuts" can be risky, there's one shortcut I take to get to a remote village that is nerve wracking, it entails going over a very rickety almost primitive wooden bridge above a river. In a large car you just wouldn't pass through, every time I take that shortcut, I silently say a Hail Mary :)

Comment: ... "longpaste"

Comment: @JohnBerryman: I know you're being funny, but that's a seriously good answer. I often use the term myself. We use shortcut for a way that is cut shorter, but it can't be cut longer, can it? Longcut doesn't make sense. All hail the longpaste.

Comment: @Hellion: Your suggestion was posted as an answer and is currently winning. You think `a scenic route` is acceptable? Or must it be `the scenic route`

Comment: I think "longcut" works fine. It's not very formal but it's obvious what it means.

Comment: I think that the issue here in part is there is no one antonym: it depends on context.  "Scenic route" is correct if you're doing it in order to have time to see the flowers.  "The long way" or "The hard way" is correct if you're telling someone they're doing more work than they need.

Comment: +1 "Scenic Route" and in the UK the strict antonym is "the long way round" or just "the long way".

Comment: @Ben: So they don't say `the scenic route` in the UK? That's useful info. Thanks.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction they do say "scenic route" in the UK, but I wouldn't say it was the strict antonym because it has an additional connotation that it is scenic.... albeit since this is Britain we often use it sarcastically "took the scenic route via the industrial estate because the bridge was closed".

Comment: @Ben: Ah! Nothing like the good old British sarcasm.

Comment: Can I question the premise? "Shortcut" doesn't seem to me to mean "the short route," it's more specific, it's a _role_ that the route serves. Like if there's a path through your backyard for people to cut through, that path _acts as_ a shortcut. It's more than just the observation that its distance is less. If that makes any sense, it's not really possible for there to be an antonym.

Comment: @nafg: Firstly, I disagree that it doesn't mean "the short route". [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shortcut) will back me up. But if you think that's the case, is there a term for when a longer route serves the role?

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction Though as per your dictionary definition, I wouldn't say it can always be used for the shortest route, i.e. if the shortest route was through a backyard as nafg mentions, it could be a shortcut; if the shortest route was the main thoroughfare through town it would just be 'the way', without being a shortcut — shortcuts have to be shorter than a 'normal' route.

Comment: Shortcuts to a destination merely have to take less time than the "normal" route, for whatever reason. Perhaps due to heavy traffic, or due to limitations of the mode of transportation (taking the highway around town to get to the other side of town may take less time than driving through the city because of traffic signals, for example).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> <sub>| It's not a shortcut, it's [*circuitous*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circuitous). → adjective, paraphrase
>
>   | It's not a shortcut, it's a [*diversion*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diversion). → not a direct path
>
>   | It's not a shortcut, it's a [*long shot*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/long%20shot). → not a safe bet, two words
>
>   | It's not a shortcut, it's a [*dead link*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dead%20link). → bad web bookmark, two words
>
>
>   [Hellion's suggestion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244699/an-antonym-for-shortcut/244710#comment529412_244699) of ***detour*** is an excellent choice as well, although his other suggestion ***scenic route*** appears to be the popular choice. I don't think *scenic route* is a good choice for the sample sentence, it seems overly redundant. But it works great in other contexts, like: *I'm enjoying our conversation, so let's take the* scenic route.</sub>

---

I believe in the context of your use case, you can use *circuitous*, or one of its synonyms (which include *indirect*, *circular*, or *roundabout*), as in:

| *It's not a shortcut, it's* **circuitous**.

> : not straight, short, and direct
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circuitous)</sub>

---

For a noun word, you can use *diversion*.

The connotation is not quite opposite of *shortcut*, but it will imply the path is not direct.

> : the act of changing the direction or use of something : the act of diverting something
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diversion)</sub>

---

When the word *shortcut* is used to indicate a relatively safe path, as in "*a* shortcut *to success*", a word with a nice ring for opposing it would be *long shot*.

> : an attempt or effort that is not likely to be successful
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/long%20shot)</sub>

---

Finally, in the use of *shortcut* in the context of a web browser bookmark, the only opposing sense I can think of is a *dead link*.

> A dead link is a link on the world wide web that points to a webpage or server that is permanently unavailable.
>   <sub>[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dead%20link)</sub>

Well, I have further reflected upon *stale link* (the link no longer points to what it originally pointed to). A little more whimsical would be to use the word [*breadcrumb*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_(navigation)):

| *It's not a shortcut, it's a* **breadcrumb**.

This would imply the web link merely takes you to a starting point to find the true thing of interest, rather than taking you directly to the thing of interest. However, it is kind of an abuse of the term, since in computer jargon, it refers to the collection of "back links" that the browser tracks for you so that you can back your way out to your starting point.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but like I said, I'm not looking for a way to paraphrase (good word, though, if I was). `Circuitous` is an adjective, and can't serve as an antonym of the noun `shortcut`

Comment: Yes. Helion's suggestion works well, or you can go with hyperbole, like *expedition* or *pilgrimage*.

Comment: Niiice! `It's a pilgrimage` sounds good. Still not an antonym, sorry :(

Comment: Along the same lines, you can go with *maze/labyrinth* or *quagmire*. The word *diversion* can be used in most other contexts, except for the bookmark thing, which I might try to use *firewall*, since it's a techie thing.

Comment: All good choices. Upvote for the persistence and the follow-through :)

Comment: A diversion doesn't necessarily have the same destination - in fact, a diversion typically leads you away from your original destination. A pilgrimage or expedition has nothing to do with shortcuts - in fact, the route taken during a pilgrimage or expedition might even include shortcuts. Really none of the options given in this answer or its comments fit the needs defined in the question. Except for circuitous, if a multi-word answer is acceptable ("circuitous route").

Comment: @talrnu: The options I presented were meant to impart the sense that the chosen path (the shortcut) does not do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 47):

Depending on the context, "Scenic route" could serve as an antonym.

Comment: Could you say anything about the article? `A scenic route` sounds wrong. Must I always say `the scenic route`? Because if so, this isn't acceptable in all cases you'd need an antonym for shortcut

Comment: You can use the indefinite article to allude to the idiom, "taking the scenic route", but the idiom itself uses the definite article. Anyone who knows this idiom will know what you mean when you say "a scenic route" - in fact, you might even need clarification if you want it to mean "a route through ample scenery" instead of "a long route".

Comment: It would be perfectly fine to say "The most direct route is the expressway, but we'll take a scenic route."

Comment: I agree that *scenic route* is an opposite, but it was redundantly so (it just means *not a shortcut*). The answer also did not provide which contexts for which it would be suitable.

Answer (score 24):

I don’t believe there is a single word in common use. The most common term I know of is *long way* or *long way around*.

I have heard (and used) *longcut* in jest. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/longcut) indicates that *longcut* may be in use, but there is a divide as to how it’s used: it indicates either the opposite of a shortcut, or a route that was *supposed* to be a shortcut but in fact turned out to be longer. [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=longcut) corroborates this.

Comment: The first usage of the phrase "Long Cut" (in the two word form) was in an Uncle Tupelo song, "The Long Cut" which dates back to 1993. Here is a link to the lyrics: http://songmeanings.com/songs/view/97883

Answer (score 20):

The thing about the word "shortcut" is that the word is positive.  "We don't have to go that way, there is a shortcut"  There is no similar opposite word because to remain positive one would need to understand why the other way is chosen.

So we have two possible opposites.  If the other way just wastes time, it is referred to as "roundabout".  This implies that any way but the shortcut way is not perfect, so you would have the one shortcut way and all the other roundabout ways.

The other word is "proper"  This means that there is something wrong with the shortcut, and there is a benefit to the other way.  "Using the calculator is a shortcut, do the math problems the proper way"

Comment: Neither of these is a noun though, and the question asks for an antonym.

Comment: On second thought, why do you think a positive word has to have a positive antonym. The very definition of antonym is against it. Good/bad; beautiful/ugly; rich/poor.

Comment: You already know that the word is not always positive. (Consider the headline "Shortcuts to Blame for Construction Accident at Asphalt Green".) So, I wonder why you open with that claim. Anyway, the OP identified the relevant use-case (correcting someone as to the length of a route), so why not focus on that, instead of intrinsic properties of the word in isolation?

Answer (score 16):

I would say: "It is not a shortcut, it is a detour."

> [Detour](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/detour) - Noun
>
> A long or roundabout route taken to avoid something or to visit somewhere along the way
>
> **Verb**, Chiefly North American
>
> A long or roundabout route taken to avoid something or to visit somewhere along the way.
>
> **Origin:**
>
> Mid 18th century (as a noun): from French détour 'change of direction', from détourner 'turn away'

Comment: it can't be detour - I see detour as being like a shortcut - a detour to here or "I got here quicker, rather than taking the long way round, I took the detour".

Comment: +1 But the answer could be improved with a source. [Detour](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/detour) - noun - a long or roundabout route taken to avoid something or to visit somewhere along the way.

Comment: @NaBob, you must be misunderstanding the word. A «détour», in the original French, is when you leave the main path to follow another one. French Canadians say «s'écarter», which has the same meaning as «se détourner». In England, some would say "roundabout" rather than "detour" because using French words is "posh" and "educated" and some people find it pretentious (to be educated).  But at any rate, the simplest answer is just "the long way."

Comment: Etymology is interesting, but English meaning is all we care about here. The English meaning of detour doesn't require the destination of the detour to have anything to do with the original journey's destination. In fact, a detour might lead to cancelling the original journey altogether. Or a detour might return you to the point you left your original journey's path from, resulting in no effective change in your path. In short, a detour has nothing to do with a shortcut, much less its opposite - it just might have a similar effect to the opposite of a shortcut.

Comment: I think detour is the perfect word. Taking a shortcut avoids part of the regular route in favour of a more direct path, while taking a detour avoids the regular route by adding an additional part to it, either because one wants to see something else off the path or because part of the original route is not possible to take.

Answer (score 4):

You can use ***byway*** and ***bypath*** figuratively.

> *bypath:* an unfrequented path; an indirect route; a byway [[Wiktionary]](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bypath)

A relevant example from *OED*:

> The by-ways and short-cuts to wealth.
>
> <sub>D. Jerrold's *The Chronicles of Clovernook*, 1846</sub>

<sub>*Note:* I was going to suggest *bypass* also but it is tricky. It can be a longer route but it takes shorter time.</sub>

---

I'm going to suggest ***circumbendibus*** as a bonus word. It is a humorous formation from *circum-* (prefix) + *bend* (n.), with the ending of a Latin ablative plural.

> *(often humorous)* A roundabout route or process [[Wiktionary]](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/circumbendibus)

Answer (score 3):

In cooking a cook can take many shortcuts, for example there's:  par-baked (parbaked) loaves, ready-made custard, ready-cooked pizzas, instant coffee, and even pre-washed, pre-sliced apples sealed in mini plastic bags. Their opposites would be

- making it the **old-fashioned way**
- cooking **from scratch**
- doing it **old-school**

As for taking short-cuts in driving the only expressions I can think of which haven't already been suggested in "answers" are:

- the **old way**
- let's take the **normal** road

Answer (score 2):

The hard way. To add to the answers already given.

Answer (score 1):

How about *digression*?  One argument for it is that it keeps the word a noun.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to English Language & Usage. I think that your suggestion has merit, but the answer would be stronger if you included a definition from a reference work or a brief comment explaining why _digression_ might be suitable as an antonym for _short cut_.

Answer (score 1):

I would say:  "It's not a shortcut, it's **the long way**".

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend usage of the word **meander** or **meandrous**

It refers to a winding or indirect course.  Typically, a river **meanders**, and your journey through thick woods will tend to be **meandrous**.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to [user1008646's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244699/an-antonym-for-shortcut#245048) you could say

> This isn't a short cut, it's the *long way round*.

Another (British English) example, which, admittedly, doesn't fit the OP's request for a single word answer, is

> This isn't a short cut, you *taken me all round the houses*.

or

> This isn't a short cut, you *taken me all around the houses*.

Note: I am sure many people will say that the expression *all round the houses* means to *pussyfoot around an issue*. I agree but, it is definitely also used to mean a tortuous (physical) route to get to a destination:

> We went all round the houses to get here, when should have just taken the
>   main road